# Error in initiating new class for AmazonPAS (AWS SDK, Product Advertising API)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS SDK and Product Advertising support available on getcloudfusion.com. I copied pas.class.php in "services" directory as instructed.

For the following code:

```
$pas = new AmazonPAS(array(
    "key" => "AKIAJ.........",
    "secret_key"=> "LFof.................",
    "assoc_id" => "736...."
));
```

I continue to get the error:

```
PAS_Exception [ 0 ]: No account secret was passed into the constructor, nor was it set in the AWS_SECRET_KEY constant.
```

But the above works for "AmazonEC2", i.e. I get appropriate XML response or error message.

I'm using ver 1.5 of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFusion no longer exists. However, if you still have the old code lying around, it's only compatible with versions of the AWS SDK for PHP *before* 1.5.

I hope this helps! :)